# Seemingly having trouble setting an ISR interrupt greater than configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, freertos

How does one set the priority of an ISR when free RTOS is ebing used?

So I have an ISR for push button that I'm setting to a higher value than `configMAX_SYSCALL_INTERRUPT_PRIORITY`, but it keeps complaining on the following line:

`configASSERT( ucCurrentPriority >= ucMaxSysCallPriority );`

Turns out `ucCurrentPriority` has 0 stored while I'm setting a priority of 100.

```
NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 100);
```

Also, `ucCurrentPriority` is of 8 bits while `priority` is of 32 bits but it's being cast to 8 bits apparently

````c
 */
__STATIC_INLINE void __NVIC_SetPriority(IRQn_Type IRQn, uint32_t priority)
{
  if ((int32_t)(IRQn) >= 0)
  {
    NVIC->IP[((uint32_t)IRQn)]               = (uint8_t)((priority << (8U - __NVIC_PRIO_BITS)) & (uint32_t)0xFFUL);
  }```
````

Comment: `100` is not a valid interrupt priority level on any micro I've ever worked with. I suggest you read up about yours and you'll probably find the limit is 15.

Comment: I see there are 16 priority levels but the max priority value goes up to 91

Comment: these are the default priority levels set for each peripheral which could be modified, yeah?
https://imgur.com/a/EyJiZwG

Comment: No. Those are the hardware priority levels which you'll only see having an effect if you assign the same software priority to multiple peripherals. You can only assign 16 levels (from 0 to 15) to a peripheral in the NVIC.

Comment: same priority to multiple peripherals? each peripheral seems to have a designated priority value

Comment: You can only assign software priorities to peripherals using the NVIC from a range of 0 to 15. So unless you're only using a couple of peripherals then some of them will share the same level. In that case the 'hardware' level from that table tells you which has higher priority of the ones assigned the same level in the NVIC.

Comment: sorry maybe I'm confusing priorities with priority levels & HW with SW priorities. The values shown in the vector table under priority column doesn't refer to the actual priority of the peripheral knowing they range between 0 and 15?

Comment: The values shown in that table are the *hardware* priorities and are not configurable. Those values only come into play if you assign the same *software* priority (0-15 range) to 2 or more peripherals and both peripherals assert an interrupt at the same time. In that case, the micro uses the *hardware* priority to decide which interrupt vector to load & execute first.

Comment: i see, and if SW priority isn't assigned, the interrupt uses the default HW priority? it's just the SW priorities are 4 bit defined, hence 16 levels?

Comment: Yes, 4-bits -> 16 levels ranging from 0 to 15. The SW priority is always assigned - if not by you in your code, then the default (typically 0) SW priority applies. So if you don't ever set the SW priority in the NVIC for your peripherals, then they'll all be the same (default) value, so the fixed HW priority applies.

Comment: but why are HW priority values on a different scale than SW priorities? if they aren't on the same scale, could even compare them? does a HW priority of 15 equate to a SW priority of 15?